# Закрыть в кавычки текст

Tags: linux, парсер, sed

Есть файл на 100к строк с примерным содержимым:

```
285570,KW,,,"",0.0000,0.0000,,
285590,KW,KU,Kayfan,"",0.0000,0.0000,,
285603,KW,FA,"Janub as Surrah","",0.0000,0.0000,,
285629,KW,HA,Hawalli,"",0.0000,0.0000,,
285663,KW,HA,Bayan,"",0.0000,0.0000,,
285704,KW,HA,"As Salimiyah","",0.0000,0.0000,,
285713,KW,KU,"Ash Shuwaykh","",0.0000,0.0000,,
285716,KW,AH,"Ash Shu`aybah","",0.0000,0.0000,,
285726,KW,HA,"Ar Rumaythiyah","",0.0000,0.0000,,
285728,KW,AH,"Ar Riqqah","",0.0000,0.0000,,
285787,KW,KU,"Kuwait City","",0.0000,0.0000,,
285788,KW,KU,,"",0.0000,0.0000,,
285799,KW,JA,"Al Jahra","",0.0000,0.0000,,
285803,KW,JA,"Al Hujayjah","",0.0000,0.0000,,
285810,KW,MU,"Al Funaytis","",0.0000,0.0000,,
285811,KW,AH,"Al Fahahil","",0.0000,0.0000,,
285815,KW,FA,"Al Farwaniyah","",0.0000,0.0000,,
285839,KW,AH,"Al Ahmadi","",0.0000,0.0000,,
285855,KW,,"Ad Dawhah","",0.0000,0.0000,,
285856,KW,KU,"Ad Dasmah","",0.0000,0.0000,,
285866,KW,FA,"Abraq Khaytan","",0.0000,0.0000,,
286091,OM,MA,"Al `Udhaybah ash Shamaliyah","",0.0000,0.0000,,
286245,OM,SJ,Sur,"",0.0000,0.0000,,
286282,OM,BS,Sohar,"",0.0000,0.0000,,
286592,OM,SS,"Samad ash Sha'n","",0.0000,0.0000,,
286621,OM,ZU,Salalah,"",0.0000,0.0000,,
286647,OM,BS,Saham,"",0.0000,0.0000,,
286696,OM,MA,Ruwi,"",0.0000,0.0000,,
286726,OM,SS,"Ar Raddah","",0.0000,0.0000,,
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как закрыть в кавычки символы между запятыми там, где их ещё нет, кроме первого и трёх последних столбцов, чтоб получилось что-то типа такого: `285603,"KW","FA","Janub as Surrah","",0.0000,0.0000,,`

### UPD

Так же в кавычках могут быть запятые и не ascii символы: `286091,OM,MA,"Al Udhaybah, ash, Shamaliyah","",0.0000,0.0000,,`

Comment: В каких полях может встречаться запятая? Как я понимаю только в 4-м? и Еще, пятое поле всегда пустое?

Comment: питоном через csv

Answer (score 4):

Если в кавычках нет запятых, то тогда можно через перловый однострочник

```
cat test.txt | perl -F, -lane '@F=map{ m/^"/?"$_":"\"$_\""} @F; print join(",", @F);'
```

UPD: Если хочется хорошо делать, то лучше использовать полноценный парсер. В репах убунту/дебиана (а наверно и других) точно есть пакет csvtool. С ним задача станет простой и легкой.

```
csvtool format '"%1","%2","%3","%4","%5","%6","%7","%8","%9"\n' /tmp/test.txt
```

Эта тула умеет ещё много чего - фильтровать, складывать вместе.

В вопросе появилось, что нужно что бы в кавычки не брало первое и три последних. Это легко исправляется

```
csvtool format '%1,"%2","%3","%4","%5","%6",%7,%8,%9\n' /tmp/test.txt
```

Comment: Проверь, не арбайтен. Забирает в кавычки все поля

Comment: работает, работает, но только немножко не так - она пустые поля в конце пропускает. Но кавычки ставит справно.

Comment: Пардон, забыл упомянуть что да, в кавычках что уже есть - попадаются и запятые и не ascii символы (если это важно). В вопрос добавлю.

Comment: Тогда можно выкинуть все выданные решения.

Comment: Если в варианте с csvtool в 4-м поле запятая будет стоять после первых двух знаков форматирование слетит. Будет   `286091,"OM","MA","Al","Udhaybah",ash,Shamaliyah,,0.0000`   вместо   `286091,"OM","MA","Al, Udhaybah, ash, Shamaliyah","",0.0000,0.0000,,`

Comment: я тестил, ничего не слетает

Answer (score 4):

```
awk -F ',' \
'{gsub("\"","");printf "%s,\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",%s,%s,%s,%s\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9}' \
test.txt
```

1) Удаляем все кавычки
2) Форматируем как нужно

**UPD**

```
awk -F ',' \
'{gsub("\"","");printf "%s,\"%s\",\"%s\",\"",$1,$2,$3;for(i=4;i<=(NF-5);i++)printf "%s,", $i;printf "\b\",\"%s\",%s,%s,%s,%s\n",$(NF-4),$(NF-3),$(NF-2),$(NF-1),$NF}' \
test.txt
```

Так вообще будет пофигу что у тебя в 4м поле

**UUPD**

```
awk -F ',|","|,"|",' \
'{printf "%s,\"%s\",\"%s\",\"",$1,$2,$3;for(i=4;i<=(NF-5);i++)printf "%s,", $i;printf "\b\",\"%s\",%s,%s,%s,%s\n",$(NF-4),$(NF-3),$(NF-2),$(NF-1),$NF}' \
test.txt
```

А вот так даже сохранит кавычки внутри поля

Comment: пробел возле запятой и кавычки ломает все

Comment: В какое место поставить пробел чтобы сломалось? `285603,"KW","FA","Janub as Surrah","",0.0000,0.0000,,`

Comment: например, так `285603,"KW","FA","Janub as Surrah", "",0.0000,0.0000,,`

Comment: `285603,"KW","FA","Janub as Surrah"," ",0.0000,0.0000,,` 1) И где что слетело? Кто сказал, что там не должно быть пробела если он есть во входящем значении. 2) Очень сильно сомневаюсь что при форматировании вывода софт, который генерит этот лист выдаст такое значение, там будет все что угодно, но не пробел после запятой при наличии кавычек в выводе 3) Про сохранение кавычек внутри поля в задании небыло ни слова. 4)Нафантазировать можно все, что угодно. Давайте реально смотреть на вещи

Comment: ну ок:) бывает всяко.

Answer (score 1):

Или сложнее вариант, явно можно упростить, но это и вы можете посмотреть как:

```
sed -E 's#^([0-9]+),([a-zA-Z ]+?),([a-zA-Z ]+?),([a-zA-Z ]+?)#\1,\"\2\",\"\3\",\"\4\"#;s#\"\"\"#\"#' test.txt
```